# How fun is The Mind with two players?

Tags: two-player, board-game-geek, the-mind

I'm deciding to buy The Mind, but before that, I wish to know how fun is playing this game with only two players? Is it worth buying if you can only play with two players most of the time?
I'm asking this, because the best way to play this game is 4 players according to BoardGameGeek.

Comment: No wonder this is one of the quietest pages on StackExchange..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is subjective, but I think the game is fun with two players.

It is fun when you really get in sync with each other.

Comment: So it's worth buying? Considering playing with only 2 players most of the time.

Comment: I have played it several weeks until we won and then the fun was over.
But is not an expensive game. And you can use the same cards to play the game.

Comment: So its replayability is not very high after winning the game?

Comment: Not with the same game group, at least for us. But still this is subjective.